# What does artisan config:cache does in Laravel 5 and how can I replicate it in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

I have been reading about optizming the configuration file in Laravel 5 by running `artisian config:cache`

The questions:

1. What does it really do?
2. Can I replicate it in Laravel 4.2, manually if needed to?

Comment: Why dont you just upgrade to Laravel 5.1 - it would take less time that trying to manually replicate a Laravel 5 feature into Laravel 4.2

Comment: Largely due to the base code not being written by us.

Comment: Still - most of the base code doesnt change - you should look into it...